# How do I create a new column that holds all the primary key values of all rows that have the same value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I read through multiple Questions here, but did not find the answer suiting my problem.

My table holds the following columns:

```
id |  name    |  fav_team
 1    John       Seahawks
 2    Patrick    Bengals
 3    Tom        Seahawks
 4    Kate       Seahawks
```

So I already figured out how to ask for all ids whose fav_team is 'Seahawks' but how do I manage to create a new column that for id 1 holds all the ids of that rows that have 'Seahawks' as fav_team as well, so that my output will look like this:

```
id    |   same_team
 1        3, 4
 3        1, 4
 4        1, 3
```

Comment: What happened to the rest of the rows?  Are you trying to get only one row for John?  Don't you want the value for all rows?

Comment: No, you're right, I want these values for all rows, gonna edit it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where do you need this new column? Is it on the same table? So what happens if you have 6 rows in that table which all of them hold `Seahawks` as their `fav_team`? Whay happens if 2000 row hold the same value? Is it a must to add a new column to this table or can you create another table to hold these relation in that new table?

Comment: You don't 'create a new column' for this. You execute a query. And process the result in your application code.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't use the right words to describe what I was trying to do, English is not my mother language so it's quite hard to use the right expressions.

Comment: For the questions above: No, it has not to be on the same table, so if I had 6 rows with ids 1 to 6, I want each id to be on the 'same_team' of every other id. It's mainly the same idea of a table with names and birthdays and I execute the query to know which person is born on the same day as another person, if I did understand it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select group_concat(id order by id)
        from t t2
        where t2.fav_team = t.fav_team and t2.id <> t.id
       ) as others_with_same_favorite
from t;
```

You can also do this with window functions, but it requires diving into JSON and doing a lot of string manipulation:

```
select id,
       trim(',' from
            replace(regexp_replace(json_unquote(json_arrayagg(id) over (partition by fav_team)), '\\[|\\]|, ', ','),
                    concat(',', id, ','), ','
                   )
           )
from t
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=02423b348624c5f558f6df97942f017b) is a db<>fiddle for this version.

Comment: Thank you!! It worked fine with your first recommendation with the correlated subquery :)

Answer (score 1):

use group_concat()

```
    select group_concat(id) from table t1
     where exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.fav_team=t2.fav_team
                  ) and
```

Comment: Upvoted, but be aware that `group_concat()` truncates its output if the list gets too long. The default length limit is 1024 bytes, but it is configurable by [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len](group_concat_max_len).